# request()->route()->getName() return wrong value on nested route groups

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

i have a group of nested routes like

```
Route::name('stores')
    Route::name('administrador')
        Route::resource('resource')
```

When i use

```
`request()->route()->getName()`
```

inside the resource it outpost

```
`storesadministradorresource.index`
```

Why does it show this? it should responde something like this

```
`stores.administrador.resource.index`
```

Comment: How do we decide what's wrong value, and what's right? Seems like in the code they simply keep on appending the names together(if I am looking at the right place) `isset($this->action['as']) ? $this->action['as'].$name : $name;`

Answer (score 0):

As codisfy mentioned,  it compiles the configuration for the group(s) and combines it with what the route has defined. The groups are just a way of cascading configuration. There are only individual routes defined in the end.

```
Route::name('stores.')...
    Route::name('administrador.')...
        Route::resource('resource', ...);
```

`stores.administrador.resource.index`

Here is the bit of code that shows the combining of the `name`/`as` property:

```
// a helper file for dealing with the concept of route groups
// Illuminate\Routing\RouteGroup@formatAs

protected static function formatAs($new, $old)
{
    if (isset($old['as'])) {
        $new['as'] = $old['as'].($new['as'] ?? '');
    }

    return $new;
}

// $name = $old . $new;
```

It concatenates things together with no separator.

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Routing - Groups - Route Name Prefix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-name-prefixes)

Comment: you have to define route like-
Route::get('/datatable', 'foldername\Controllername@methodname');